How does polars load parquet files into dataframe?
I am trying to load a parquet files where total size of the data (Total size of the parquet files) is 240 GB. I calculated the size of the columns using duckdb using the following query:
import duckdb
con = duckdb.connect(database=':memory:')
print(con.execute("""SELECT SUM(total_compressed_size) AS 
  total_compressed_size_in_bytes, SUM(total_uncompressed_size) AS
  total_uncompressed_size_in_bytes, path_in_schema AS column_name from
  parquet_metadata('D:\\dev\\tmp\\parq_dataset\\*') GROUP BY path_in_schema""").df())

Through this query, I am finding out that one column named L_LINENUMBER has size of 4 GB when compressed and 4.5 GB when uncompressed.
When I am doing following polars and trying to load that into the polars dataframe then size of the column is coming as 91 GB
import polars as pl

df = pl.scan_parquet("/home/ubuntu/parquet_files/")
selected_df = df.select("L_LINENUMBER")
df_size = selected_df.collect(streaming=True).estimated_size("mb")
print(df_size) ## Coming as 91 GB

I want to know why so much change when it is loaded into data frame? I can understand that it may take 1x or 2x but it is going two digit-x
Do you have any idea if these look like the correct numbers? I am not able to find explanation of this except for one thread there it says that it Return an estimation of the total (heap) allocated size of the DataFrame.
